# How do I get the fingerprint reader to work in Ubuntu 21.04? (XPS 15)

Tags: drivers, dell, 21.04, fingerprint-reader

I've tried [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/ixwgm0/xps_15_9500_ubuntu_popos_fingerprint_howto/) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/hpzsd2/how_to_get_the_fingerprint_reader_working_on_dell/). Following the second linked post, `fprintd-enroll` spits out `Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available`

After following the first linked reddit post, there isn't an option in user settings to setup the fingerprint. Same applies to [this](https://gist.github.com/stefanovazzocell/22798cd9f5df331020c6beb1b3020369) script. Any ideas how to make this work?

lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 27c6:5395 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 SE HERO Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6723 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Laptop: Dell XPS 15

CPU: i7-9750H

GPU: GTX 1650

RAM: 16GB

SSD: NVMe

Comment: Without knowing whether your machine can even see the fingerprint reader, answering this question will be rather difficult. Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `lsusb`? This will provide actionable information 

Comment: @matigo Done. The Goodix fingerprint reader is in the list so it can see it. I've also done the apt update; apt upgrade jazz many times so I don't think that's the problem either.

Comment: I found the solution [in this thread](https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Broadcom-58200-fingerprint-sensor-Linux-support-Precision-3541/td-p/7650511/page/1) and compiled [the solution here](https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Broadcom-58200-fingerprint-sensor-Linux-support-Precision-3541/m-p/8207735/highlight/true#M9660):
My notebook is a Dell Latitude 5500.

Answer (score 1):

It’s very rare for Shenzhen Goodix to release a Linux driver for their fingerprint readers as the company generally does *just enough* to ensure its Windows drivers operate. However, because this is being used by a Dell — and because Dell wants their machines to be fully compatible with Ubuntu — [there is a driver available](http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/pool/public/libf/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/)!

Here’s how to install it:

1. Download the `libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.6-0ubuntu1~somerville1_amd64.deb` package file using your browser of choice or via the Terminal like:

   ```
   wget -O ~/Downloads http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/pool/public/libf/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.6-0ubuntu1~somerville1_amd64.deb
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Download the `0.0.6` package or something newer. The original `0.0.4` package is garbage and only ever worked when Dell installed Ubuntu before shipping the device.</sup>
2. In Terminal, install the package with `dpkg`:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.6-0ubuntu1~somerville1_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Reboot
4. Register the fingerprint sensor:

   ```
   fprintd-enroll
   ```
5. Configure your device

Starting with 21.10, you may not need to do this anymore as [Linux kernel 5.12 and newer will support the device](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:27c6-5395) out of the box.

Comment: Still doesn't work: `Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available`. Idk what it is, but everything seems to be broken. My graphics drivers also completely gave up: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1363044/nvidia-settings-and-drivers-absolutely-broken

Comment: From what I’ve read, a lot of the hardware has better support with the newest kernel, so you may want to try running [a live 21.10 USB session](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) to verify if everything is working properly. Though 21.10 is still in testing, it’s pretty solid 

Comment: Can I actually install 21.10 or am I limited to a live USB session? Isn't 21.10 still in an early state?

Comment: Yes, you can install 21.10 if you elect to. It is still in testing, with a final release scheduled for next month. Testing with a Live USB will simply let you know ahead of time whether everything is working or not.

Comment: In the udev/rules.d of the linked driver only the following ids are mentioned:
27c6:538c , 27c6:533c ,  27c6:530c and 27c6:5840

Why would this driver work for the 27c6:5395 as mentioned in the starting post. Or is the list in udev not complete?

Comment: This does not work on Pop OS 20.10 at Jan 2022.
It failed at step 2, even with versions of 0.0.4 or 0.0.6.

With `lsusb`, Pop OS can detect the fingerprint, but no option for using it on Settings.

Comment: Pop!OS != Ubuntu 

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned `libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.6-0ubuntu1~somerville1_amd64.deb` doesn't support 27c6:5395

There is some work in progress in libfprint:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/189
closed, and moved here
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/376

Also there are some examples communicating with this device here:
https://github.com/goodix-fp-linux-dev/goodix-fp-dump

But nothing that can be called production quality driver for this device so far. As of 12/16/2022