# nvidia-settings and drivers absolutely broken

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 21.04, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

Boy is Ubuntu not being nice to me today. *I'm sort of a beginner in Linux but I still have basic knowledge and I know what I'm doing most of the time and won't just willy nilly do whatever a guide/tutorial tells me to.*

I don't know when this could've happened, but when I installed Minecraft and noticed I was playing on integrated graphics so I checked NVIDIA X Server Settings to see what's up. Half of the settings were missing. I don't remember which, but "PRIME profile" was still there where I could select the on-demand profile, best performance or the integrated graphics (I selected best performance). Hopped back on MC and nothing changed. Opened NVIDIA X Server Settings again to see that ALL of the settings had dissappeared besides the PRIME profile one. Hmm.

I've tried installing an older driver (460), `sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*` and then `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, repairing broken packages and deleting the Monitors.xml file.

`nvidia-smi` spits out `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`. Considering everything I'm pretty sure that this is a driver issue. But I've got the latest and greatest, even tried downgrading which didn't help. Secure boot in BIOS is disabled. At first I though that NVIDIA released a completely broken driver and when I apt updated sometime today, it installed it and broke it. But that wouldn't explain why the older driver doesn't work. I'm out of ideas, are you?

Dell XPS 15 7590:

```
CPU: i7-9750H
GPU: GTX 1650
RAM: 16GB
SSD: 512GB NVMe
```

Edit: Good news (sort of)! After a restart nvidia-settings now shows this:

```
ERROR: Unable to find display on any available system


(nvidia-settings:4729): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 22:47:14.758: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 22:47:14.761: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 22:47:14.761: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 22:47:14.789: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 22:47:14.789: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
** Message: 22:47:14.789: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes
```

ubuntu-drivers devices:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F91sv00001028sd00000905bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id ==
modalias : dmi:bvnDellInc.:bvr1.13.0:bd07/22/2021:br1.13:svnDellInc.:pnXPS157590:pvr:sku0905:rvnDellInc.:rn0VYV0G:rvrA00:cvnDellInc.:ct10:cvr:
driver   : oem-somerville-meta - third-party free
```

sudo lshw -c display:

```
*-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:165 memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:166 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

dpkg -l | grep nvidia-

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64                    470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-470                        470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-470:amd64                 470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-470:i386                  470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-470:amd64                  470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-470:i386                   470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-470:amd64                  470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-470:i386                   470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-470:amd64                   470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64                    470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-470:i386                     470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-470:amd64                      470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-470:i386                       470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64                    470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386                     470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-34-generic  5.11.0-34.36                                                         amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-34
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04  5.11.0-34.36                                                         amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-470 for the generic-hwe-20.04 flavour
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-34-generic  5.11.0-34.36                                                         amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-34 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-34-generic   5.11.0-34.36                                                         amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-34-generic
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-470                    470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-driver-470                           470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-470                    470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-470                    470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.16.1                                                             all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                             470.57.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.1                                           amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-470                            470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                     0.18build2                                                           all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470               470.63.01-0ubuntu0.21.04.2                                           amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Comment: Reinstalling Ubuntu seem to have fixed the drivers. The only thing I could blame is `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` that I added to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub. I am writing this as a comment because it is not a solution. `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` fixed the tearing but without it everything is quite unusable as the upper and lower halves of my display are 1 second apart. It's a lot worse in games also.