# Driver for Realtek USB2.0 Finger Print Bridge FocalTech Fingerprint Device

Tags: drivers, realtek, fingerprint-reader

Ubuntu is not showing fingerprint setup in settings

device: Vivobook-ASUSLaptop-M6500IH-M6500IH
OS: Ubuntu 22.04

is there any way of fixing it

**lsusb** does show it

Bus 003 Device 015: ID 2808:a658 Realtek USB2.0 Finger Print Bridge FocalTech Fingerprint Device

Comment: Have you explored https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406999/i-cant-use-fingerprint-sensor-in-ubuntu-22-04 and perhaps this older one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362986/how-do-i-get-the-fingerprint-reader-to-work-in-ubuntu-21-04-xps-15

Comment: i tried fprintd libpam-fprintd but doing fprintd-enroll throws following error

Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available